# Android multiple EditorActionListeners on single EditText field

Tags: java, android

I have multiple action listeners defined for single EditText field,
one in the Activity:

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(this);
```

and another in the View definition:

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {...});
```

Is there a way for both listeners to run? Now only the one in the Activity runs. 
I can't change(simplify/refactor) the code to make all this be at single place(because it's complicated as hell). 
Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a Reference of the previous OnEditorActionListener when u set a new OnEditorActionListener

In new OnEditorActionListener call to the previous one.

Comment: Hmmm, I could do that also. It won't be as easy as I thought but... So in the first one I will return false to note that I have not consumed the action and in other true.